# Regarding AWS/SQL and Django

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services

I am working on deploying a Django app via AWS, and I am using an RDS instance (MySQL) to store information. However, when I try to connect, I get an error like,

"(1045, "Access denied for user 'wsgi'@'(ip address)' (using password: YES)").

I've been just following the steps on the AWS website to do this, any ideas how I can fix this in my code?

Could my requirements.txt be an issue? Thanks!

Comment: Your ec2 does not have access to Rds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Access denied" meaning you have to add permission to your DB.

Comment: Thanks! What's the best way to do that from the AWS console?

Comment: I hope this blog helps http://blog.backand.com/support/connect-to-database/enable-remote-connections-to-mysql-on-amazon-rds/

Comment: Yep, this definitely got me on the right track! Thanks!